# How to use a simple select in entity framework 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

How can I query my Entity Framework 6 object by the primary key.

I have the following code:

```
using (var db = new bookEntities()){
    var books = db.books.where // this doesn't work as work command is not available

     var books = from b in db.books
          where b.book_id == 1
          select b; // results in compilation error: "Could not find an implementation of the query pattern of source type System.Data.Entity.DbSet...
}
```

db.books return `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<book>`

My goal is to implement Eager Lazy loading, but I need to know how to access the data first. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx), but it's not working for me.

Worht mentioning that I am running the code within a class in ASP.NET 4.5 web projects with entity Framework 6 (latest version). I followed several tutorials, but always get the same results.

At the top of the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
```

When running the project I get:

```
Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Design.AspNet.EntityDesignerBuildProvider'.
```

Thanks

Comment: `db.books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.book_id == 1)` should work for you. Your `DbContext` has a `books` `DbSet<T>` property right? What does `bookEntities()` return?

Comment: What is bookEntities ?

Comment: **Eager Lazy Loading** is Oxymoron since *Eager Loading* is the opposite of *Lazy Loading*.

Comment: VS shows: bookEntities.bookEntities() when hovering on bookEntities(). It's a class created by EF6 when it generated the objects based on the MySQL database.

Comment: you're missing the `new` keyword to instantiate your object context. `using (var db = new bookEntities())` ....

Comment: My mistake, I have the new keyword ,wrote it wrong. sorry for that. But still experiencing the issue.

Comment: Ah so `bookEntities` is your db context? `var book = db.books.FirstOrDefault(b => b.book_id == 1);` should work. Not sure what you mean by command is not available because it comes from `System.Linq`.

Comment: In the using block add the namespace for entity framework. Should be System.Data.Entity; now try again to write the where method.

Comment: How did you add EntityFramework to your project, was it through NuGet?  If not remove the reference, then install EntityFramework through NuGet.

Comment: @MikeC Installed it via NuGet

Comment: is this a Web **Site** or a Web **Application** project?

Comment: @MikeC Web Application

Comment: I'd recommend trying it first in just a console app.  Start by running 'Install-Package EntityFramework' in the Package Manager Console, then add the same data model that you're using in the web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your using statement is fine.  It should be using System.Linq.  Not using System.Data.Linq.

Check that you have the proper reference in your web.config file:

```
<assemblies>

    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />

</assemblies>
```

Answer (score 1):

Random guess, since I don't have a setup where I can test this, but I think you'd need:

```
using System.Data.Linq;
```

Comment: Hi, I get "The type of namspace name Linq does not exist in the namespace System.Data

Comment: I've added a reference and it now compiles. I'll see if it works.

Comment: Reference `System.Data.Linq.dll`

Comment: referencing the System.Data.Linq in the reference manager didn't solve it. I still get the Type of namespace name 'Linq' does not exist error

Comment: Maybe I am missing a reference for the assembly in the web.config?

Comment: If you've referenced `System.Data.Linq` and you still can't find `System.Data.Linq` namespace, then you've got something else going on.

Comment: Why would you try to add reference to System.Data.Linq in a EntityFramework application? System.Data.Linq is just for LINQ-TO-SQL and not LINQ-TO-Entities?!?